# Cypher: Nested FOREACH build a "real number tree". Problem is making deeper loops conditional so smaller numbers are higher precision

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to build a tree of real numbers between 0 and 6000, the precision of the tree is to vary as follows: from 0-100 the tree depth will go on to 3 decimal places i.e. 0 to 99.999, from 100 to 500 will be 2 decimal places, 500 to 1000 just 1 decimal place and from there to 6000, no decimals.  The idea is that I can then use this tree to represent millimetres, litres, kg - whatever property that needs a real number to define it. Then I can describe the property units as a property in the relationship to the real number node rather than having having separate node sets for mm, kg etc (or, worse: length, width, height - all mm) all thousands of nodes)

My problem is that I can't make the conditional FOREACH loops work. generating nodes down to unit level works a treat. I am not experienced in coding at all and I am probably missing something simple but I have tried a bunch of approaches including generating the unit precision nodes first and then trying to add the higher precision nodes later as well as this attempt to do them all in one shot, which seems neater.

```
MERGE (hub:RealNumber {name:'Real Numbers', mag: 'hub'})
MERGE (zero:RealNumber {name: 0.000, mag: ['eplus3', 'eplus2','eplus1', 'eplus0', 'eminus1', 'eminus2', 'eminus3']})
WITH hub, range(1000,6000,1000) AS thousands, range(100,900,100) AS hundreds,range(10,90,10) AS tens, range(1,9,1) AS units,
range(1,9,1) AS tenths
FOREACH (thousand IN thousands|
    FOREACH (hundred IN hundreds |
        FOREACH (ten IN tens |
            FOREACH (unit IN units |
                //FOREACH (tenth in tenths |

        MERGE (a1:RealNumber {thousand:thousand, name:toFloat(thousand), mag: 'eplus3'})<-[:TENTHS]-(hub) // creates thousand nodes and connects to hub

        MERGE (b1:RealNumber {hundred:hundred, name:toFloat(hundred+a1.name), mag: 'eplus2)'})<-[:TENTHS]-(a1) // creates hunded nodes chid to thousands
        MERGE (b2:RealNumber {hundred:hundred, name:toFloat(hundred), mag: 'eplus2'})<-[:TENTHS]-(hub) //creates hundred nodes child to hub

        MERGE (c1:RealNumber {ten:ten, name:toFloat(ten+a1.name), mag: 'eplus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(a1) //creates ten nodes child to thousand >hundreds
        MERGE (c2:RealNumber {ten:ten, name:toFloat(ten+b1.name), mag: 'eplus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b1)//creates ten nodes child to hundreds
        MERGE (c3:RealNumber {ten:ten, name:toFloat(ten+b2.name), mag: 'eplus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b2)
        MERGE (c4:RealNumber {ten:ten, name:toFloat(ten), mag: 'eplus1'})-[:TENTHS]-(hub) //creates ten nodes child to hub 

        MERGE (d1:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+a1.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(a1)
        MERGE (d2:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+b1.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b1)
        MERGE (d3:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+b2.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b2)
        MERGE (d4:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+c1.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c1)
        MERGE (d5:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+c2.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c2)
        MERGE (d6:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+c3.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c3)
        MERGE (d7:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit+c4.name), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c4)
        MERGE (d8:RealNumber {unit:unit, name:toFloat(unit), mag: 'eplus0'})<-[:TENTHS]-(hub)   

        FOREACH (tenth IN tenths IN CASE WHEN a1.thousand<1001 THEN [1] ELSE [] END |

        MERGE (e1:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+a1.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(a1) //WHERE e1.name<500
        MERGE (e2:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+b1.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b1)
        MERGE (e3:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+b2.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(b2)
        MERGE (e4:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+c1.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c1)
        MERGE (e5:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+c2.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c2)
        MERGE (e6:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+c3.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c3)
        MERGE (e7:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1+c4.name, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(c4)
        MERGE (e8:RealNumber {tenth:tenth, name:toFloat(tenth)*0.1, mag: 'eminus1'})<-[:TENTHS]-(hub)   

        )))))
```

On a related subject - will find efficiency be improved if I link the nodes along "NEXT_THOUSAND", "NEXT_HUNDRED" lines or just simply sort them all and use a "NEXT" through the lot?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need each number in its own node? Do you need to find all measurements with a specific numeric value, regardless of the unit?

Comment: My thinking is that, by doing this I can ask questions of the database as a whole "which engines have a bore between 80 and 95.2 mm and a stroke of less than 85mm and produce more than 75 kW/litre. If I am taking the wrong approach I am more happy to change!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) to quickly find nodes with a property value within a range. You should not create nodes for a limited set of values.

Using the engine example mentioned in your comment, let's say the data model is as follows (the unit for each property is fixed by you, and does not need to be stored):

```
(:Engine {id: 123, bore: 85.75, stroke: 80, powerDensity: 77.789})
```

After you create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Engine(bore)`, `:Engine(stroke)`, `:Engine(powerDensity)`, you can efficiently perform queries involving any of the indexed properties (or all of them).

For example:

```
PROFILE MATCH (e:Engine)
WHERE (80 <= e.bore <= 95.2) AND e.stroke < 85 and e.powerDensity > 75
RETURN e
```

When multiple indexed properties are used in the same `MATCH`, then only one of the indexes may be used (but the Cypher planner will try to pick the index that is most likely to get the fastest results).

Comment: Hi and thanks very much for that insight. I wonder if I might engage in a little discussion about why I didn’t do it that way? It means engine nodes with hundreds of properties - which I understood was bad practice? Splitting the properties across a number of subnodes could be done but still leave nodes with dozens of properties. Hence my planned structure of (e:Engine)-{:BORE ]->(n:Real{name:82}).  That is why I am trying an approach based on a time tree –but does this detail change your advice? Is something different again more appropriate?